# Using a regex to get a Nokogiri node

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm parsing an XML file with Nokogiri.

Currently, I'm using the following to get the value I need (the document includes multiple `Phase` nodes):

```
xml.xpath("//Phase[@text=' = STER P=P(T)         ']")
```

But now, the uploaded XML file can have a `text` attribute with a different value. Thus, I'm trying to update my code using a regular expression since the value always contains `STER`.

After looking at a few questions on SO, I tried

```
xml.xpath("//Phase[@text~=/STER/]")
```

However, when I run it, I get

```
ERROR: Invalid predicate: //Phase[@text~=/STER/] (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)
```

What am I missing here?

Alternatively, is there an XPATH function similar to starts-with` that looks for the substring within the entire value and not just at the beginning of it?

Comment: We need more information. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need the minimal XML and code in the question that demonstrates the problem. Without those you're asking us to imagine the situation. Also, given that code and the minimal XML, what is the required output? Currently you're asking us to guess and that's off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code: first off, [there is no `=~` operator in XPath](https://w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-precedence-order). The way to test whether text matches a regex is using the [`matches` function](https://w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-functions-31-20170321/#func-matches):

```xml
//Phase[matches(@text, 'STER')]
```

Secondly, [regex matching is a feature of XPath 2.0](https://w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#string.match), but [Nokogiri implements XPath 1.0](https://rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri#Features).

Luckily, you are not actually using any regex features, you are simply checking for a fixed string, which can be done with XPath 1.0 using the [`contains` function](https://w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-functions-31-20170321/#func-contains):

```xml
//Phase[contains(@text, 'STER')]
```